# Create a textarea field in symfony2.0

Tags: symfony

How to create a textarea field in symfony2.0?Plesae provide an example also.I am new in symfony.

Comment: Did you even try [google](https://www.google.ie/search?q=symfony2+textarea&oq=symfony2+textarea&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l3j62l2.6649&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)? The first result looks decent to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
$builder->add('lyrics','textarea')
```

just add a new parameter 'textarea'

Comment: Yes, ok, nice answer ..... but where to put this snippet of code? This answer is incomplete (at least to me, even if I know where to put this snippet of code)

Comment: @DonCallisto: where you have to make form builder class,in that class having a function like this:

Comment: @webdeveloper: I perfectly know where to put that snippet of code.... I mean that the answer was incomplete since he didn't specified where to put it ....

Answer (score 0):

@DonCallisto

where you have to make form builder class,

```
 class ArtistType extends AbstractType {
 /**
 * builds the form for a category
 * @param FormBuilder $builder
 * @param array $options 
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('artistname')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('paypalemail')
        ->add('lyrics','textarea')
}
/**
 * returns a unique name of the form
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{        return 'artist_';    }
```

}